# Why is it okay to compare a pointer with '\0'? (but not 'A')

Tags: c++

I found a bug in my code where I compared the pointer with '\0'.

Wondering why the compiler didn't warn me about this bug I tried the following.

```
#include <cassert>

struct Foo
{
    char bar[5];
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    Foo* p = &f;
    p->bar[0] = '\0';
    assert(p->bar == '\0');    // #1. I forgot [] Now, comparing pointer with NULL and fails.
    assert(p->bar == 'A');     // #2. error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer
    assert(p->bar[0] == '\0'); // #3. What I intended, PASSES
    return 0;
}
```

What is special about '\0' which makes #1 legal and #2 illegal?

Please add a reference or quotation to your answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What makes it legal and well defined is the fact that `'\0'` is a *null pointer constant* so it can be converted to any pointer type to make a *null pointer value*.

ISO/IEC 14882:2011 4.10 [conv.ptr] / 1:

> A *null pointer constant* is an integral constant expression prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the *null pointer value* of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type. Such a conversion is called a *null pointer conversion*.

`'\0'` meets the requirements of "integral constant expression prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero" because `char` is an integer type and `\0` has the value zero.

Other integers can only be explicitly converted to a pointer type via a `reinterpret_cast` and the result is only meaningful if the integer was the result of converting a valid pointer to an integer type of sufficient size.

Answer (score 5):

`'\0'` is simply a different way of writing `0`.  I would guess that this is legal comparing pointers to `0` makes sense, no matter how you wrote the `0`, while there is almost never any valid meaning to comparing a pointer to any other non-pointer type.

Comment: and 0 is converted to the `nullptr` (in C++11 parlance)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I don't think it is in this case. The null pointer constant is directly converted to the null pointer value of the appropriate type.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, no, it's an object of type `std::nullptr_t`. It is, however, considered a null pointer constant along with `0`, and as such it *converts* to a null pointer value of the appropriate type.

Comment: Actually, aren't character literals in C++ of type **char**, as opposed to C where they are **int**? If so, then shouldn't a C++ compiler give an error if you try to compare a char with a pointer, without an explicit typecast? (note that implicit integer promotions do not apply if pointers are involved).

Comment: @Lundin: an integral constant expression can have any integer type, not just `int`. `char` is an integer type.

Answer (score 1):

This is a design error of C++. The rule says that any integer constant expression with value zero can be considered as the null pointer constant.

This <strike>idiotic</strike> highly questionable decision allows to use as null pointer  `'\0'` (as you found) but also things like `(1==2)` or even `!!!!!!!!!!!1` (an example similar to one that is present on "The C++ programming language", no idea if Stroustrup thinks this is indeed a "cool" feature).

This ambiguity IMO even creates a loophole in the syntax definition when mixed with ternary operator semantic and implicit conversions rules: I remember finding a case in which out of three compilers one was not compiling and the other two were compiling with different semantic ... and after wasting a day on reading the standard and asking experts on c.c.l.c++.m I was not able to decide which of the three compilers was right.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a design error in C, considering that this feature was inherited from it? (not that I agree with you about the idiocy of that decisions)

Comment: @avakar: I don't think so. Actually C and C++ rules for the null pointer are different and also type conversion rules for C++ are by far more complex so no real "backward compatibility" is present. For example the quite common `#define NULL ((void *)0)` that is (was) used in C system headers is not a valid `NULL` definition for C++.

Comment: Not that it matters, but what was the case you remember?

Comment: @avakar C allows the NULL constant to be anything, as long as it is compatible with null pointers. In C++, null is always 0 and there is nothing magic with it.

Comment: I wasn't talking about `NULL`, I was talking about `0`. Isn't it a null pointer constant in C as well?

Comment: `(1==2)` is indeed a null pointer constant in C. So the so-called design error is also present in C. C *could* have defined that `(void*)0` is a null pointer constant, but `0` is not, required `NULL` to have type `void*`, and if so would be approximately the same that C++ would be if `nullptr` were the only null pointer constant. I'm not sure whether you're saying it's a design error to preserve backward compatibility, or whether it was a design error in the first place to have `1==2` as a null pointer constant. If the latter then it's a C error only, if the former then it's both.

Comment: Oh, unless of course Bjarne or some other pre-standard C++ developer invented this idea of all 0-valued integral constants being null pointer constants, and then C stole it, and that's how it got into C89. In which case it's a kind of combined double-team C and C++ error.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I simply mean that C and C++ pointer semantic is not compatible anyway, and indeed IIRC many C compilers were using `((void *)0)` for `NULL` for example. This means that to compile C source code that uses this convention to C++ you need to change it anyway so changing it to `nullptr` would have been better. I think having a keyword for the null pointer from the beginning would have been a more sensible choice for C++ (and it's not about avoiding new keywords... C++ has many including pointless ones like `mutable` or `and` that are hopefully due to committee effect).

Comment: @EddyPronk: I'll try to dig it back. It was in early '90 when I was still in the phase "C++ template programming is the best thing in the world" and I was checking all my code using three compilers. Basically it was a problem due to the interaction of 1) Implicit constructor from int, 2) Implicit conversion to void * 3) The ternary operator type conversion rules 4) the use of "0" (a compiler thought it was a `NULL`, another thought it was a good idea to convert it to an object instance and the third one was leaving it as a integer and stopping compilation because of type error).